# CSS content attribute for current item

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

Is there any "native" HTML/CSS way to use the

```
:before { content: ''; }
:after  { content: ''; }
```

attributes to the current statement (instead of a pseudo before or after element)?

Something like that?

```
.current-item {
    content: 'New';
}
```

## Edit

Background: I would like to do a responsive workaround for a long word that I would like to replace by a shorter word by using

```
@media (max-width: 680px) {}
```

Comment: No, if you're trying to add content with CSS, that's what these pseudo elements are for; the content for the current item is otherwise defined in HTML. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to do a responsive workaround for a long word that I would like to replace by a shorter word by using `@media (max-width: 680px)`.

Comment: Why not have both words in there, hide the small one at full size, then hide the large one at small size?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this using either `before` or `after` and making the content invisible somehow (probably set a 0 width or something). Or like @slime said, use two spans and have only one visible at a time.

Comment: Setting the width to 0 is what I already tried. But @slime's comment is a good approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current CSS specifications define the `content` property as applying to `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements only. There have been drafts that would allow much wider use, but they have mostly not been implemented. WebKit browsers let you specify an image value only, e.g. `.current-item { content: url(New.png) }`, but you probably need a cross-browser solution.

What you can do is to have two elements and switch between them in display, as suggested in comments. You can make one of the alternatives content proper in HTML and the other one generated content, using an element with empty content. An advantage is that then the page content proper, as “seen” e.g. by search engines and in non-CSS rendering, has just one of the alternatives. Example (click on “Full page” to see the wide-viewport rendering):

```html
<style>
@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .current-item {
     display: none;
   }
   .current-item-2:after {
     content: "New";
   }
}
</style>
<span class=current-item>Totally renewed</span><span class=current-item-2></span>
```

Comment: That's very nice, especially because it only contains one regular element (in respect to search engines or CSS less devices).